# How to rectify Routing error for rails 3 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload

I am doing a simple file upload using Rails 3, followed all the steps as given in the following link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails-2.1/rails-file-uploading.htm

getting following error in browser:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"app/controllers/Upload/uploadFile", :controller=>"upload"}
```

I am getting following error in windows command prompt (for ruby and rails)

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"app/controllers/Upload/uploadFile", :controller=>"upload"}):
1: <h1>File Upload</h1>
2: <% form_tag({:action => 'app/controllers/Upload/uploadFile'},
3:                         :multipart => true) do %>
4: <p><label for="upload_file">Select File</label> :
5: <%= file_field 'upload', 'datafile' %></p>

app/views/upload/uploadfile.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_upload_uploadfile_html_erb___217229071_35578596'
app/controllers/upload_controller.rb:3:in `index'

Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.0ms)
```

Comment: That's a scary tutorial full of weirdness. And why follow a Rails 2.1 tutorial if you're using Rails 3? Just find a paperclip or carrier wave demo app. Might as well learn using something current.

Answer (score 0):

You just want

`<% form_tag({:action => 'uploadFile'} ... %>`

Comment: thanks Kris, but it had to be :action => index, came to knw thru rake routes